# how to fit/pack a graph into a 2d grid without destroying the connectivity?

Tags: algorithm, sparse-matrix, graph-theory

Given a graph like the one below, I try to pack/fit this graph into a fixed rows 2d grid and use as few columns as possible. I can change the shape of the graph, but not the connectivity.

For example, the available grid has a fixed row size of 11, and the original graph has a row size of 7. Each o represents a vertex and a vertex only connects to its adjacent neighbors. The black o are vertices on a row; every black o only has one or two neighbors. The red o are "bridges" connecting a different row of black o, which can have more than two neighbors.

There are two constraints for transformation:

1. The previous adjacent vertices are still adjacent.
2. Two nonadjacent vertices cannot be adjacent after transformation.

To simplify the question, I do not change the shape of the red vertices (although they may be transformed) and only change the shape of the black vertices.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRETX.png]

A possible solution is shown below:

[image]

This problem can be thought of as using as few resources(columns) as to store the graph. The current solution is manually made.

I'm considering using a heuristic algorithm to solve it. For example, search for the chain of black o that consume the fewest columns between the red parts, but I think a better algorithm could exist for this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dependency'  What is the significance of the red and black circles?  Are they the vertices of your graph?  Where are the edges?

Comment: rotate by 90° would only need 7 columns. So you should first define which transformations are allowed,

Comment: @ravenspoint Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question.  Every o are vertices, and edges connect the adjacent vertices.

Comment: @MrSmith42Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question. The row number is fixed, hence cannot just rotate by 90°.

Comment: The single of vertices is spelled vertex.  English!

Comment: "the available grid has a fixed row size of 11, and the original graph has a row size of 7"  What does this mean?  Both pictures in your question have 11 rows

Comment: @ravenspointSorry for the typo. The first graph has seven rows, but the available space has 11 rows. In the second picture, the seven-row graph is transformed into an eleven-row graph and hence fits into the space.